# How to split the string in hive table

Tags: hive

I have a table `emp`, It looks like this:

```
+----------+----+
|customerID|name|
+----------+----+
|         1| Ram|
|         2| Raj|
+----------+----+
```

I want to split the string of each record and I want the output as below in Hive:

```
+----------+----+---+
|customerID|name|req|
+----------+----+---+
|         1| Ram|  R|
|         1| Ram|  a|
|         1| Ram|  m|
|         1| Ram|   |
|         2| Raj|  R|
|         2| Raj|  a|
|         2| Raj|  j|
|         2| Raj|   |
+----------+----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the name column to array type in hive and then explode to get the desired result.
Example:

```
+----------+----+
|customerID|name|
+----------+----+
|         1| Ram|
|         2| Raj|
+----------+----+

select *,explode(split(name,'')) as req from emp

+----------+----+---+
|customerID|name|req|
+----------+----+---+
|         1| Ram|  R|
|         1| Ram|  a|
|         1| Ram|  m|
|         1| Ram|   |
|         2| Raj|  R|
|         2| Raj|  a|
|         2| Raj|  j|
|         2| Raj|   |
+----------+----+---+
```

Remove the blank spaces.

```
select customerID,req  from (select *,explode(split(name,'')) as req from emp) where req != ''

+----------+---+
|customerID|req|
+----------+---+
|         1|  R|
|         1|  a|
|         1|  m|
|         2|  R|
|         2|  a|
|         2|  j|
+----------+---+
```